# How to get next param in linux shell command params?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm writing a shell script of this command:

```
ovs-dump -i dpdkb2 [-d in] [-p tcp] [host 192.168.102.2][port 80] [-w /test.pcap]
```

For '-w' options, I want to process '/test.pcap' into '$PWD/test.pcap', so I write script like this:

```
for arg
do
    case $arg in              
        -h | --help)
            ...
            ;;
        -w )
            echo "OPTARG=$OPTARG"
            ;;
        ?)
            ;;
    esac
done
```

As we see, I want to get '/test.pcap' by '$OPTARG', but is none. So my question is how to get 'test.pcap' in my script?

When I use 'getopts' like this:

```
while getopts "w:h:" arg
    do
        case $arg in              
            -h | --help)
                ...
                ;;
            -w )
                echo "OPTARG=$OPTARG"
                ;;
            ?)
                ;;
        esac
    done
```

When I run `sh ovs-dump -w a.pcap`, I got error: '/usr/local/share/openvswitch/scripts/gangyewei-ovs-dump: line 68: -w: command not found'.

And the output of 'echo "OPTARG=$OPTARG"' is 'OPTARG='.

It's also not work, what should I do? Thank you~

Comment: You should be using `getopts`

Comment: 'getopts' also not work, refer to new edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your script as this:

```
OPTIND=-1   # rest OPTIND if it has been set earlier

# start getopts loop
while getopts "w:h:" arg; do
    case $arg in
        h | --help)
            ...
        ;;
        w)
            echo "OPTARG=$OPTARG"
        ;;
        ?)

        ;;
    esac;
done
```

Then run it as:

```
bash ./ovs-dump -w a.pcap
```